# angularjs - Trouble returning data from a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a db factory that returns data from the database to the client after the data is successfuly posted but it returns as 'undefined' for some reason.

My factory function looks like this:

```
uno.factory('adbFactory', ['$http', function($http){

    var fact = {};

    fact.get = function(http, query, isAll) {
        //var query = "get all blog_posts";
        http.post('php/adb/adb.php', {'query': query, 'all': isAll})
        .success(function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log('Error...');
        });
    };

    return fact;

}]);
```

And my controller resembles this:

```
uno.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope, $http, adbFactory){
    $scope.derp = 'derp!!!!!';
    console.log(adbFactory.get($http, 'get users 1', false));
});
```

don't worry about the 'get users 1 etc etc' string, i created a function in php that renders a SQL query based on given parameters. Is there something in my factory code i need to improve on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice returning the promise from the factory and handling the success and error events in the controller instead.

```
fact.get = function(http, query, isAll) {
    return http.post('php/adb/adb.php', {'query': query, 'all': isAll});
};

uno.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope, $http, adbFactory){
   adbFactory.get($http, 'get users 1', false).success(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: I can console.log the data no problem but it doesnt return to the controller. and by returning the promise, wht exactly do you mean ?

Comment: I have tried to clarify what i mean, but editing my comment.

Answer (score 1):

`fact.get` method has no return statement, that's why it returns `undefined`.

Also, this callback is useless because it is called asynchronously

```
.success(function(data){
   //console.log(data);
   return data;
 })
```

I think you want somethig like:

```
fact.get = function(http, query, isAll) {
   return http.post('php/adb/adb.php', {'query': query, 'all': isAll});
};


uno.controller('newsCtrl', function($scope, $http, adbFactory){    

    adbFactory
    .get($http, 'get users 1', false)
    .success(function(data){
         console.log(data);
     })
     .error(function(){
         console.log('Error...');
     });

});
```

Comment: How exactly would I write it? like return function() { fact.get = function(){...} }

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind that you are performing some **asynchronous** request.

You have two way to retrieve your data :

- Following the callback way
- Following the promise way

As you know, **$http** service return promise, and has some callback method, like **.success()** and **.then()** for example.

For promise, **$q.defer()** is a **promise manager** from the **deferred API**.

**$q.defer()** get 2 methods :

- resolve(value) : which resolve our associated promise, by giving her the final value
- reject(reason) : which resolve an promise error.

So you can do :

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($http, $q){

    var defer = $q.defer();

    //Callback way
    function get(callback){
      $http.get('app.php').success(function(data){
        //Pass our data to the callback
        callback(data);
      });
    }

    //Promise ways
    function getPromise(){
      $http.get('app.php').success(function(data){
        //Resolve the data
        defer.resolve(data);
      });
      //Return our promise
      return defer.promise;
    }

    return {
      get: get,
      getPromise: getPromise
    };

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {

  //Our callback method
  function print(data){
      console.log(data);
  }

  //Retrieve our data by using callback way
  Service.get(print);


  //Retrieve our data by using promise way
  var promise = Service.getPromise();

  //When promise is resolved
  promise.then(function(data){
    //Retrieve our data
    console.log(data);
  });

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

But what should i use ? I think that use **promise** is better than callback, because you can handle easily your request. Moreover, you can perform **promise chaining**, and avoid the famous **callback hell**.

Comment: Ahhh So i see! It also seems promises keeps strict control of data handlng as well. I like the use of callbacks though it seems to save code and easier to read in some cases for people but I understand it clearly